# scala even type number

Tags: scala, types

The only way I can think of doing this, without creating a wrapper class, is to use scala 3's type unions like this

```scala
type Even = 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8
val even : Even = 4
```

but that obviously has a limit. Is there a way to create the "entire" range?

As a follow up, what about for other ranges? Is there some way to create a function that restricts the type in some arbitrary way (as dangerous as that sounds)?

Comment: Look for refined types... although, IMHO, once the refinement becomes too complex is better to just validate at runtime, you can avoid the wrapper using `opaque types`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a newtype with a smart constructor. Several ways to do it.

First, manually, to show how it work:

```
trait Newtype[T] {

  type Type

  protected def wrap(t: T): Type = t.asInstanceOf[Type]
  protected def unwrap(t: Type): T = t.asInstanceOf[T]
}

type Even = Even.Type
object Even extends Newtype[Int] {

  def parse(i: Int): Either[String, Even] =
   if (i % 2 == 0) Right(wrap(i))
   else Left(s"$i is odd")
  
  implicit class EvenOps(private val even: Even) extends AnyVal {
    
    def value: Int = unwrap(even)

    def +(other: Even): Even = wrap(even.value + other.value)
    def -(other: Even): Even = wrap(even.value - other.value)
  }
}
```

You are creating type `Even` which compiler knows nothing about, so it cannot prove that an arbitrary value is its instance. But you can force-cast to it an back again - if JVM in runtime won't be able to catch some issue with it, there is not problem (and since it assumes nothing about `Even` it cannot disprove anything by contradiction).

Since `Even` resolves to `Even.Type` - that is type `Type` within `Even` object - Scala's implicit scope will automatically fetch all implicits that are defined in `object Even`, so you can place your extension methods and typeclasses there.

This will help you pretend that this type has some methods defined.

In Scala 3 you can achieve the same with `opaque type`. However this representation, has the nice side that it is easy to make it cross compilable with Scala 2 and Scala 3. As a matter of the fast, that's what [Monix Newtype](https://newtypes.monix.io/) did, so you can use it instead of implementing this functionality yourself.

```
import monix.newtypes._

type Even = Even.Type
object Even extends Newtype[Int] {

  // ...
}
```

Another option is older macro-annotation based library [Scala Newtype](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype). It will take your type defined as `case class` and rewrite the code to implement something similar to what we have above:

```
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype

@newtype case class Even(value: Int)
```

however it is harder to add your own smart constructor there, which is why it usually is paired with [Refined Types](https://github.com/fthomas/refined). Then your code would look like:

```
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype

@newtype case class Even(value: Int Refined numeric.Even)
object Even {

  def parse(i: Int): Either[String, Even] =
    refineV[numeric.Even](i).map(Even(_))
}
```

However, you might want to just use the plain refined type at this point, since `Even` newtype wouldn't introduce any domain knowledge beyond what refinement does.

Comment: Just wow! I'm coming from TypeScript, and stuff like this is semi-magic. But this is on another level! Specially the regex refinements, I could spend months adding refinement types to everything! Thank you for your in-depth answer :D

Comment: You are welcome. If I may I'd suggest to use refined types to generate validation out-of-the-box for things that don't have a strict domain name, but in your business logic create new types - in whichever way you prefer - to both validate AND separate use cases (e.g. separate types for Username, FirstName, LastName, etc). This provides some additional measure for self documentation and testing: you would not accidentally swap FirstName and LastName, and when you see that something is converted to Username you'd knew its use case immediatelly, as opposed to plain String value.