# Define new type whose domain is subset of another type in Scala

Tags: scala, domain-driven-design, scala-3

Using the example of even numbers, I would like to define the Even type whose  domain is even integers *using* the function
`val isEven(i: Int): Boolean = i % 2 == 0`

How would I do this in Scala 3 using the opaque keyword...

`opaque type Even = ??? // use Int and filter using isEven` or if that does not work,

```
type Even = ???
```

The rationale is to use functions as a building block to create new types, rather that complicating matters by using newtype as [scala-even-type-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901159/scala-even-type-number) or using [Refined Types](https://github.com/fthomas/refined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
object Evens:
  opaque type Even = Int

  object Even:
    def apply(i: Int): Even = if i % 2 == 0 then i else sys.error(s"$i is odd")
    def unsafe(i: Int): Even = i
    def safe(i: Int): Option[Even] = Option.when(i % 2 == 0)(i)

  extension (x: Even)
    def toInt: Int = x
    def +(y: Even): Even = x + y
    def *(y: Int):  Even = x * y
    def half: Int = x / 2
end Evens

import Evens.*
// val x: Even = 2 // doesn't compile
val x: Even = Even(2)
// val x: Even = Even(3) // RuntimeException: 3 is odd
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-opaque-types.html

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/opaques.html

If you'd like `Even(3)` to fail at compile time rather than runtime then replace `def apply(i: Int): Even = ...` with one of the following implementations

```
import scala.compiletime.{error, erasedValue, constValue, codeOf, summonFrom}
import scala.compiletime.ops.int.%
import scala.compiletime.ops.any.{==, ToString}

inline def apply[I <: Int with Singleton](inline i: I): Even =
  inline erasedValue[I % 2] match
    case _: 0 => i
    case _    => error(codeOf(i) + " is odd")
```

```
inline def apply[I <: Int with Singleton](inline i: I): Even =
  inline if constValue[I % 2] == 0 then i else error(codeOf(i) + " is odd")
```

```
inline def apply[I <: Int with Singleton](inline i: I): Even = 
  inline erasedValue[I % 2 == 0] match
    case _: true => i
    case _       => error(constValue[ToString[I]] + " is odd")
```

```
inline def apply[I <: Int with Singleton](inline i: I): Even = 
  summonFrom {
    case _: (I % 2 =:= 0) => i
    case _                => error(constValue[ToString[I]] + " is odd")
  }
```

```
inline def apply(inline i: Int): Even =
  inline if i % 2 == 0 then i else error(codeOf(i) + " is odd")
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html